# PrimeFaces editor value display without tags

Tags: jsf, primefaces

```
<p:editor id="message" value=" #{user.contact}" width="600" height="500" style="margin-left: 20px;"></p:editor>
```

Above code helps me to save a text with style(as editor has the control property).
But when I display the saved text as "h:outputtext", it comes out with tags. something like:

```
<br>asdasa</br>edw<b>sdcsdcsc</b>
```

if i display the save text in editor, I am unable to hide the control property. So how can I show a text with style and without tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to show unescaped text use:

```
<h:outputText value="#{somebean.somevalue}" escape="false" />
```

Comment: You don't need reputation to mark an answer as accepted. See the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) how to do so.